# Android App running from local environment.After hosted in Market and downloaded from that its not running in the modules I have used GSON

Tags: json, gson, google-play

Hi, I am developing an android application using GSON library. If I can run that application in local environment it works fine. After deploying in android market and downloaded that application from market is not running in which areas am integrating that GSON.

Comment: Seems like you are downloading content from the net. Are you sure you are not using localhost in the liver version of the app as well?

Comment: in live environment am using the live url only.put the gson jar in libs folder also.

Comment: In that case, we would need to see logs if we are to help. :-)

Comment: is any problem or issues with progaurd.

Comment: After download app from market and do any operation this is am getting:                                java.lang.NullPointerException
package_name.bu.a(Unknown Source)
package_name.bu.onPostExecute(Unknown Source)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)

Comment: Progaurd is implemented.When i remove that working fine

Answer (score 3):

You need to add these lines to your proguard and then gson class is kept while signing your app.. This will get you going.

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature


# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```

Comment: You might have to add more lines than is stated here, but it is without a doubt a proguard error. Your best bet is to test the signed app package before uploading to google play.

Answer (score 1):

```
check once comment the prorogard file and host in the server and check its working or not if its working fine problem with progard configurations
```

Comment: yes am comenting the progaurd and upload in market its working fine.i hope some configuration problem in progaurd i think.Thanks.